# Two divs, each within two divs - how can I change the stacking order using CSS (for responsive)?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

Preface: I cannot change the HTML.

To better explain my question, I have provided an illustration below. Essentially, I have two rows of divs - the first row has content, and the second row would have a button beneath the content.

I want to make the page responsive, so that the div with a button always is below its corresponding div with content, but the extra container divs are proving a challenge. Any ideas?

[What I have (above) and what I want (below).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57KBV.png)

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="choice-section">
    <div id="choice_1" class="choice odd" style="margin-top: 242px;">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
    </div>
    <div id="choice_2" class="choice even" style="margin-top: 322px;">
        <div class="content">asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="vote-choice odd">
        <a class="vote btn" href="javascript:void(null)" choice="1">Vote</a>
    </div>
    <div class="vote-choice even">
        <a class="vote btn" href="javascript:void(null)" choice="2">Vote</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, however Google didn't turn up anything for me, and beyone absolute positioning and setting the sizes of the divs to be all the same height, I can't think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly reccomend looking at [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) grid and column system with which this can easily be achieved. This framework will make responsive design a breeze for you.

You can see an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/taIi5sdugQe4iI8JrYX3?p=preview) of something pretty similar to what you are trying to achieve in a Plunker I very quickly put together

CSS:

```
.blue {
  background-color:blue;
  height:200px;
}

.red {
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
}

.purple {
  background-color:purple;
  height:200px;
}

.green {
  background-color:green;
  height:200px;
} here
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="green">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great and I have no problem doing that, however the HTML in my example can't be changed and isn't as friendly as your code. I appreciate your time and thoroughness of your response..